# List names in recycler View

Tags: java, android

I made a RecyclerView, now I want to list all the names. but it showing only last name.

```
 public void DataInserted(){

    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){

        ModulData modulData= new ModulData();
        modulData.setName("name1 " +i);

        mNotes.add(modulData);
    }
     adpterSearch.notifyDataSetChanged();

 }
```

and this is the adapter where I declared the setName()

```
     @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {
     viewHolder.textView1.setText(mNotes.get(i).getName());
    }
     @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mNotes.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        TextView textView1;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            textView1 =itemView.findViewById(R.id.text_id);


        }
    }
```

Comment: To clarify: you want a total of 20 elements, but only get 5?

Comment: You need to post the code to `setName`, but I suspect it edit a string instead of adding to a list of strings.

Comment: @pappbence96 sorry i edited, no i want to print 5elements,but i'm getting only one element.

Comment: it would be better if you send more codes such as adapter, XML, etc...

Comment: @Guy ,what you mean ?

Comment: @ismail You need to post minimal code. In your example you are adding only one entry, you don't show how you print it, and you don't show what `setName` does. You should also add any other relevant code.

Comment: @Guy yeah i have only one entry , i posted the adapter class.

Comment: @ismail How do you want to print 5 entries if you add only one?

Comment: @Guy i wanna print "name1" 5times since i'm using for Loop.

Comment: @ismail There is still a lot of data missing. Please go over [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

change your code to:

```
public void DataInserted(){

    for(int i=0;i<5;i++){

        ModulData modulData= new ModulData();
        modulData.setName("name1 " +i);

        mNotes.add(modulData);
        adpterSearch.notifyItemInserted(i);;
    }
 }
```

Comment: Is the height of the layer that you display text `wrap_content`? because if it be `match_parent` displaying just one item.